# Powershell iSeries DB2 ODBC returns "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Tags: powershell, db2, odbc

Summary:  Powershell 5 using 64 bit ODBC driver for DB2.  SQL query Select "Count(*)" works.  Query for actual data "Select field" returns an error.  32 bit ODBC driver will not work at all.  One answer here pointed to an ODBC setting (Convert binary data ...) for conversion but that did not resolve the problem.

Code:

```
$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT MMITNO,
       MMITDS
FROM MITMAS
WHERE MMCONO = 3 
  AND MMITNO = '2658591351'
"@

$Db2Connection = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$Db2Connection.connectionstring = "DSN=DB2_MR0P_64;Userid=USSRF_ADM;Password=########"
$Db2Connection.open()

# Set up to run the query
$SqlCmd = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($SqlQuery,$Db2Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($SqlCmd)
$DataTable = New-Object system.Data.datatable
$RowCount = $DataAdapter.fill($DataTable)

$Db2Connection.close()

# Process the returned datatable
$DataTable.Table[0] | ForEach-object {
  write-host "Total rows in MITMAS is $("{0:N0}" -f $_)."
}
```

Returns:
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
At C:\PowerShellScripts\TestDB2.ps1:19 char:1
+ $RowCount = $DataAdapter.fill($DataTable)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OverflowException

To be quite frank, my knowledge of what i'm using is very limited and i've been successful by copying and pasting various posts from you experts.  So, i apologize if the answer is simple and i'm just not seeing it.  The only machine i have any control over is the local PC with no admin rights on the iSeries machine.

Comment: It looks like you're closing the connection then trying to read data from it. I would try closing the connection _after_ you're done reading the data.

Comment: Same results if i move the $Db2Connection.close() to after the Write-host statement.  The error occurs before the execution of the close().  It happens during execution of the fill($DataTable).

Comment: Sounds like something someone more familiar with iSeries or that database would need to answer. You can also create an ODBC connection from another application (e.g., Excel) and see if you get different results.

Comment: The same query works in Microsoft Access 2013 using a 32 bit version of the ODBC driver.

Comment: Sounds like you have a workaround then. I don't know how you'd get this done in PowerShell; sorry.

Comment: @RickInGarland yes don't close in any language until you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Powershell as x86. I had same issue.

- When I started script in powershell x64 + ODBC driver x64 = same
  error appear
- When I started script in powershell x86 + ODBC driver x64 = NO Error

```
$system = "System"  
$driver = "iSeries Access ODBC Driver"
$username = “USER”
$password = “AnyPass”

$SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM LIBRARY.TABLE"

$Db2Connection = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$Db2Connection.connectionstring = "Driver=$driver;System=$system;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password;"

$Db2Connection.open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($SqlQuery,$Db2Connection)
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 15

$DataSet = new-object System.Data.DataSet 
$DataAdapter = New-Object system.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($SqlCmd)

[void]$DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

 foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) 
 {
    $Row
 }
$Db2Connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill method work with dataset, not datatable.
modify you code like this:

```
 $DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($SqlCmd) 
 $DataSet = new-object System.Data.DataSet 
 $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) 
 {
   #your traitment here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  However, the new Fill still gives the same  "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." error.

Comment: MMCONO is a numeric field or a char field?

Comment: It is decimal (3 long, 0 decimals)

Comment: Can you put all your code, the error message and the descriptif of your table please?

Comment: The entire program is in my original post.  After i discovered the problem, i cut all the fluf from the program to eliminate other possible reasons.  The error is also in the original post.

Comment: Here is the schema definitionn for the first few fields but it does not paste well and i don't know how to include a screen capture here.
Column name Description Data type Length Decimals Edit code Indexes
MMCONO Company Decimal 3 0 00,01,02,10,11,20,30,40,50,60,61,70,80,90
MMSTAT Status String 2 20,80
MMITNO Item number String 15
00,01,02,10,11,20,30,40,50,60,61,70,80,90
MMITDS Name String 30 10

Comment: have you try your query directly in your database?